# Cannot add content types from hub with Site Script and Invoke-SPOSiteDesign

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-design, site-script

I am attempting to add Content Types form Hub to a site through a site script and then Invoke the site design through the script.

The site script seems to work if I use the UI to add the content type, but if I use the Invoke-SPOSiteDesign no library gets created nor the Content Type. The issue is not with creating the library in this way, but adding the Content Type which seems to be the issue.

My understanding is that MS introduced a change in January which changed the model from a Push to a Pull and perhaps this is why I cannot get this to work .
Code I tried:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/site-design-script-actions.schema.json",
    "actions": [

        {
            "verb": "addContentTypesFromHub",
            "ids": ["0x010100DDBD569668068847AA25B8576A1270C8"]
        },
        {
            "verb": "createSPList",
            "listName": "Documents1",
            "templateType": 101,
            "subactions": [
                {
                    "verb": "addContentType",
                    "name": "Benefits",
                    "id": "0x010100DDBD569668068847AA25B8576A1270C8"
                }
                        ]
        }


    ],
    "bindata": {},
    "version": 1
};


Invoke-SPOSiteDesign -Identity f4d4a3d6-b11d-417e-859e-e213ff2c059a -WebUrl https://mysite
```

Has anyone else had this issue recently?

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue and couldn't find a solution yet. I am applying two SiteDesigns via the REST API (_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.WebTemplateExtensions.SiteScriptUtility.ApplySiteDesign) in a PowerAutomate workflow to a newly created Site. The first SiteDesign will be applied, with the same issue that Content Types don't get added to the library, the second SiteDesign doesn't get applied at all. However, via the UI everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with SiteDesign and more actions then 30 per Site-Script. `AddSiteDesignTaskToCurrentWeb` is the new REST endpoint for site designs, which provides the ability to overcome the 30 action limit. This new endpoint now allows for 300 actions or 100k characters in a site script (or cumulative across all site scripts in a given Site Design). The only parameters required to execute a site design task is to pass in the site design using the `siteDesignId` property.

URI: `_api/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities.WebTemplateExtensions.SiteScriptUtility.AddSiteDesignTaskToCurrentWeb`

Headers:

```
{
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
}
```

Body:

```
{
"siteDesignId" : "38ef12db-e8b8-4716-96d9-7556c61bf98b"
}
```

Example from Power Automate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked awhile ago, but I had this problem and could find no answers, but I finally managed to make it work and maybe this will help someone else looking for answers.

The problem for me was that when I initially ran the script, I'd copied the JSON from the GetSiteScriptFromList endpoint and after it ran it created the site columns using "createSiteColumnFromXml" rather than letting the "addContentTypesFromHub" action handle it.

I manually deleted the content typees and any added site columns and kept attempting the content type hub but it always failed, and when I visited the /Lists/ContentTypeSyncLog address, the error I noticed was an internal column name conflict. I connected to the site through powershell to list out all of the current site columns and sure enough, the problem column was still there despite not appearing under site columns in the browser. As soon as I used powershell to delete the column, everything ran smoothly and as expected.

Also, the problem column was a MMS column, so I had to delete two columns, one named "InternalName" and the other named "InternalName_0". But if MMS columns work for hub content types in the site script action, I have to assume any column type will work.

TLDR; Check the sync list for errors on the trouble site at /Lists/ContentTypeSyncLog and also verify there are no columns with name conflicts anywhere, hidden or otherwise. Remove any that exist.